# Select top level list items only with Cufom, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cufon

The below JS is selecting all of the list items, i need to select only the top level list item anchors.

HTML and Cufon below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     Cufon.replace('#navigation ul#nav li a', {
         textShadow: '#dedede -1px -1px',
         hover: { color: '#2a668f' }
     });
 </script>

<ul>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>
  <li><a></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
Cufon.replace('#navigation ul#nav > li > a'
```